# EnligherJS Wordpress Plugin - not able to highlight the code properly

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting

I am using EnligherJS wordpress plugin on my blog, and recently I noticed that it's not highlighting the code properly.

it was working fine few months back, so not sure if that's the wordpress upgrade or the plgiun upgrade which created this issue.

wordpress version: 6.2.2
plugin version: 4.6.1

And This is how my python code looks like. Seems like it's using mysql highlighter for my python code, even though in language I have choose python.

[image]